# ask for version control server (client) from VssConnection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Dears

Please help me to work with VssConnection from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.15.134.0-preview package

I need to get pending changes for workspace, query it for conflict and commit 
This is how i do it with TfsTeamProjectCollection and

```
var vssCred = new VssClientCredentials();

using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, vssCred))
{
    collection.Authenticate();

    var scs = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    var scsProject = scs.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);
    var workspace = scsProject.VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace(localPath);

    var pending = scs.QueryPendingSets(new string[] { "$/" }, RecursionType.Full, workspace.Name, loginName);
    if (pending.Any())
    {
        var pendingChanges = new[] { pending.First().PendingChanges.First() };

        var validation = workspace.EvaluateCheckin2(CheckinEvaluationOptions.Conflicts, pendingChanges, "", null, null);
        var conflicts = validation.Conflicts;
        if (conflicts != null && conflicts.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Join("\r\n", conflicts.Select(_ => string.Format("{0} {1}", _.Message, _.ServerItem)));
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("conflict was found\r\n{0}", message));
        }
        var res = workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, "test checkin");

        TestContext.WriteLine("checked in {0}", res);
    }

}
```

However there are [vsts integration samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=vsts) that uses VssConnection object 
How can I get the same VersionControlServer from VssConnection instance?

I've tried to find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebAPi (like Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi) but failed.

```
var vssCred = new VssClientCredentials();
using (VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(uri, vssCred))
{
    var prj = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();

    var p = prj.GetProject(teamProjectName).Result;

    //i'd like to get prj.VersionControl here       

    //or something like var scs = connection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
}
```

Is it possible to get versionControlServer from VssConnection? Should I continue to use TfsTeamProjectCollection to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

You could use TfsTeamProjectCollection as before, as there is **no** workspace method in VssConnection:

```
TfvcHttpClient tfvcClient = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
List <TfvcItem> tfvcItems = tfvcClient.GetItemsAsync("$/", VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result;
```

More examples, you can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=vsts

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how to retrieve the pending change?

Comment: @PhilS you can do it the same as before from TfsTeamProject collection `TfsTeamProjectCollection collection; var vcs = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); vcs.QueryPendingSets(...);`

Comment: @oleksa, thank you, but this is an example for the Extended Client, not for the TfvcHttpClient.